# Repository that extends JpaRepository cannot be autowired into my Service

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, autowired

I have UserRepository Interface that extends Jpa REpository Interface when Im trying to autowire it into a Servise or a Controller I recieve such an error -

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.boottestfinal.UserHelper required a bean of type 'com.example.boottestfinal.UserRepository' that could not be found.
```

my project structure just in case - [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrttj.png)

UserRepository -

```
package com.example.boottestfinal;

import com.example.boottestfinal.enities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Service -

```
package com.example.boottestfinal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.example.boottestfinal.enities.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserHelper {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    public UserHelper(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Entity -

```
package com.example.boottestfinal.enities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "usertable")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
//    @SequenceGenerator(name = "userSequence", sequenceName = "userSequence", allocationSize = 1)
//            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "userSequence")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    int age;
    String name;

    public User(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If its not enough for an answear I can provide with more Information
I am new to Spring Boot, hope someone helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using constructor injection and field injection at the same time, you really should be using 1. So either:

```
@Autowired    
private final UserRepository userRepository;
```

or

```
private final UserRepository userRepository;

public UserHelper(UserRepository userRepository) {
   this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

But I don't believe this is whats stopping you from creating a bean and using it for dependency injection. Looking at your project structure, I see your main class **BootTestFinalApplication** is in the config folder. Could you move that class into the package **com.example.boottestfinal**.

So the issue you was facing was that your main application was unable to register the UserRepository as a bean in the application context as by default it only does component scanning in the package its present in. Since your main class is in the config package, it will only do component scanning there and won't pickup the UserRepository.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Spring Boot's Component Scan principle.
By default, SpringBoot must register `@Bean`, `@Service` and `@Controller` as Singleton Bean in the BeanContainer to use DI for each other.

And it's the `@ComponentScan` that does this.
SpringBoot has a `@ComponentScan` inside the `@SpringBootApplication`.
The most important thing is where this annotation is located.

The solution is simple.
The location of the `BootTestFinalApplication` class is not a `config`  package.
Move to `com.example.boottestfinal` , which is the highest package.
Then all your Bean will be registered in the container and DI will work normally.

It's good to see the [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html#using-boot-locating-the-main-class).